# UE4.27 spectator crach

Tags: crash, unreal-engine4, spectator

I have a spectator in an unreal(4.27) CPP game project. The spectator will play video on its own client. Sometimes, it crashes and I get this log:

> LogWindows: Error: Assertion failed: bOk [File:D:/Build/++UE4/Sync/Engine/Source/Runtime/MediaUtils/Private/MediaPlayerFacade.cpp] [Line: 2629]

I find the reason is that the queue size of `VideoSampleSinks` is larger than `FMediaPlayerQueueDepths::MaxVideoSinkDepth`.

So what can I do to avoid it?

I've no idea what to do next, the error seems to occur in the engine code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.